# XStream error when have two tags with same name

Tags: xstream

I have two tags in my xml file: "article_periodic" and "article_magazine". Inside of this tags I have
the "article" tag.

When I set (xst is instance of XStream)
xst.alias("article", ArticleMagazineVO.class);

Error: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException is not defined as field in type ArticlesInPeriodic

This is because I have two objects for the same name of tag. Is possible outline this problem?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <my_xml>
       <article_periodic>
          <article>
            <doi></doi>
            <title></title>
          </article>
        </article_periodic>

        <article_magazine>
            <article>
                 <autor></autor>
                 <magazine_name></magazine_name>
            </article>
       </article_magazine>
   </my_xml>
```

Comment: you can make List<article> inside class ArticlesInPeriodic and ArticleMagazineVO and add annotation @XStreamImplicit